# Multidimensional array results with joins

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm joining tables and I'd like to get multidimensional query results based on my joins.

```
# AppBundle:ProductRepository

$this->createQueryBuilder('pr')
    ->select('pk.id', 'pk.name', 'pr.id', 'pr.label')
    ->join('pr.package', 'pk')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

As you can see `Product` is linked to a `Package` (many to one)

Here is the kind of result I'm getting:

```
array(
    array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'package 1', 'id1' => 1, 'label' => 'product 1'),
    array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'package 1', 'id1' => 2, 'label' => 'product 2'),
    array('id' => '2', 'name' => 'package 2', 'id1' => 3, 'label' => 'product 3'),
)
```

Here is what I'd like to get:

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'package 1',
        'products' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'label' => 'product 1',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2,
                'label' => 'product 2',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'package 2',
        'products' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 3,
                'label' => 'product 3',
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Is there a way to hydrate this kind of multidimensional array with Doctrine 2 ?

*I mean with Doctrine 2, not with "post prod" php loops*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a combination of [partial results](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax) with an [array hydrator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats). Try:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('pr')
    ->select('partial pk.{id, name}, partial pr.{id, label}')
    ->join('pr.package', 'pk')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult()
;
```

Comment: This is really interesting. However your example is listing `products` with `packages` attached instead of `packages` with `products` isn't it ? How can I reverse ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY It's a hard for me to reproduce a working example, as I don't have you exact db structure. But it's actually really simple. Just think how you would write a *normal* dql statement that selects and joins all the data you need. From there reduce it to only the values you want by using the partial-syntax and array hydration.

Comment: Another thing might be that it seems you're in the wrong repository. You create a query builder with root alias `pr`, but then start with `pk`. Creating a query builder this way *implicitly* sets the `FROM` part on the dql.

Comment: @Yoshi please remove "." (dot) before label

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use partial results and model one-to-many relation. Example:

In your controller:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
      ->select('partial author.{id, name}, partial articles.{id, title, content}')
      ->from('Module\Model\Author', 'author')
      ->leftJoin('author.articles', 'articles');
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$results = $query->getArrayResult();
```

And don't forget to use OneToMany relation. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

So, in the model Author.php write this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Articles", mappedBy="author")
 */
private $articles;

public function __construct() {
    $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I've made some small algorithm to join the data to the form you've described.

```
$source = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'package 1', 'id1' => 1, 'label' => 'product 1'),
    array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'package 1', 'id1' => 2, 'label' => 'product 2'),
    array('id' => '2', 'name' => 'package 2', 'id1' => 3, 'label' => 'product 3'),
);

// Here is what I'd like to get:

$target = array(
    array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'package 1',
        'products' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'label' => 'product 1',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2,
                'label' => 'product 2',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'package 2',
        'products' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 3,
                'label' => 'product 3',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

// id => item
$map = array();

foreach($source as $item)
{
    // prepare product
    $product = array(
        'id' => $item['id1'],
        'label' => $item['label'],
    );
    if (isset($map[$item['id']]))
    {
        // push data to existing item in $map
        $map[$item['id']]['products'][] = $product;
    }
    else
    {
        // create new item in $map
        $map[$item['id']] = array(
            'id' => $item['id'],
            'name' => $item['name'],
            'products' => array($product),
        );
    }
}

function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2) {
    $difference=array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            if( !isset($array2[$key]) || !is_array($array2[$key]) ) {
                $difference[$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                if( !empty($new_diff) )
                    $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
            }
        } else if( !array_key_exists($key,$array2) || $array2[$key] !== $value ) {
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $difference;
}

$new = array_values($map);
var_export($new);

echo "\ndiff: ";
$diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($target, $new);
var_export($diff);
```

The function array_diff_assoc_recursive is borrowed from Giosh here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Comment: Thank you for your R&D but this is the kind of "post prod" I wanted to avoid